# How to show code from Jsfiddle or Github in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created my own personal blog . The free one in wordpress not the premium. I want to show some of my examples from github and jsfiddle in my blog .

Is it possible in free version of the wordpress ? I am not sure.

I am new to word press. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't comment since I'm too new to the site, but are you using the self-hosted downloaded off of wordpress.org or are you using the free hosted wordpress.com? (If your blog link is username.wordpress.com then it's the hosted version)

If you're using the hosted wordpress.com version, you cannot install plugins, but you can embed Github Gists by "copy/pasting the URL out of your address bar onto its own line in the post editor." As quoted from: http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/spotify-rdio-and-github-embeds/ Doesn't look like they support embedding anything else from Github yet though.

If you're using the self-hosted version, you can install a plugin (such as the github embed plugin) using the "Plugins" screen (it shows up under Appearance on your admin panel, see screenshot below). Full instructions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins
[image: wordpress plugins screen]

Answer (score 4):

**Embedding js-fiddle without any plugin**

1. Go to you fiddle and at top menu, click on **Embed**
2. You can see a pop-up like this [image]
3. Now at the bottom, you can see written **Embed code** and infront on that you have option to choose either **Use script** or **Prefer iframe**.

[image: On selecting Use script] [image: On selecting Prefer iframe]

4. For Wordpress you need to select iframe and then copy the ifram code given i the box.
5. Now in you Wordpress editor go to **Text** mode instead of **Visual** mode and paste the copied code.
6. Now switch back to **Visual** mode and you can see js-fiddle embedded in your blog.

Comment: nice it helped me. therichpost.com

Comment: sure..:). stay in touch with therichpost.com

Comment: @ajay-m sure, you can also have a look at logic24by7.com

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm a free wordpress user too, as example.wordpress.com.
I thinks the best option you have is to store your codes in gist from github and use the embed link in your wordpress site.

e.g. if have a file in: 
https://gist.github.com/AlyssonJalles/9503c6c5d3dc63e9a561
you must look for the "direct link" to post on your site. The direct link is obtained removing the user name and the termination .git in the link, as: https://gist.github.com/9503c6c5d3dc63e9a561.

After that you go into your wordpress site, open the page editor and turn off the "visual" and paste the direct link there. It's cool because when you update your code there (in Gist) your wordpress page will be updated as well.
In your published page you will see the embed link from Github like this (Run Code Snippet too check out!).

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/AlyssonJalles/9503c6c5d3dc63e9a561.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to share a jsfiddle on your blog.

1. Under Posts click Add New
2. In the top right corner of the main content textarea you can pick between a Text editor and Visual editor. Pick Text.
3. Go to your jsfiddle page, click Share in the top menu and copy the iframe code.
4. Paste the iframe code in the Text view of the main content of your post.

Don't forget to add some text explaining the project ;)

As for github, I don't think they offer an embedding functionality by default however you can use a WordPress plugin to embed your projects: https://wordpress.org/plugins/github-embed/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Where is the option for installing plugin in WP admin?

Comment: I have followed the way you told but on the link appears on my blog not the full ediotor.